# ZPanel on CentOS 6 uses 6Gb disk space. Need to understand what is using the space

Tags: centos

Installed ZPanel on CentOS 6. Mails, mysql and files may use ~ 100 mb. Now see that all files uses disk space ~ 6 Gb.

Tried with `ncdu` and see this [image: http://jmp.sh/v/1dnKe4SUVzSk06026tJg]

How to see what is using ~ 6 Gb (some list with big size files)?

With  `df -h`

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/simfs             10G  6.7G  3.4G  67% /
none                   16G  4.0K   16G   1% /dev
none                   16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
```

Tried `find /root -type f  -size +1000k -exec ls -lh {} \; | awk '{print $5 ": " $NF}'` See nothing.

Tried

```
# du -hs /
du: cannot access `/proc/18577/task/18577/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `/proc/18577/task/18577/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `/proc/18577/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `/proc/18577/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
6.7G    /
```

Tried

```
du -sh /*
6.0M    /bin
12K     /boot
4.0K    /dev
67M     /etc
4.0K    /home
23M     /lib
4.0K    /lost+found
4.0K    /media
4.0K    /mnt
4.0K    /opt
du: cannot access `/proc/18689/task/18689/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `/proc/18689/task/18689/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `/proc/18689/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `/proc/18689/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
0       /proc
184K    /root
7.0M    /sbin
4.0K    /selinux
4.0K    /srv
0       /sys
8.0K    /tmp
780M    /usr
5.8G    /var
```

So, need to check `/var`

Ohhhh `5.5G    /var/zpanel/logs`. Crazy... Need to disable logs (or set limit)

Comment: `du -hs /`, then `du -hs /large-directory`, then `du -hs /large-directory/large-subdirectory`. Repeat until you've found which deep directory is unexpectedly large.

Comment: Tried, but get `cannot access`

Comment: Do it with `sudo` then.

Comment: Get like this `usage: sudo [-D level] -h | -K | -k | -V
usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-D level] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-u user name|#uid]
` But have no knowledge what to do with it...

Comment: Sorry, I slightly mucked up my example. `sudo` is pretty basic sysadmin stuff. Try `sudo du -hs /*`, then `sudo du -hs /large-directory/*`, and so on. Some "no such file or directory" messages are normal.

Comment: Thanks. Now, clear. must check `/var`

Comment: Yep. `sudo du -hs /var/*` will give you the sizes of the folders in `/var`, so you can keep stepping down. I'll bet `/var/log` is your next spot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ncdu image is pretty much useless to us as it shows us the contents of root's home directory /root. You should try using it on / and work down from there.

Alternatively you can try

```
du -h --max-depth=1 /
```

Take a careful look at the output to determine which directories are holding all the data. Lets assume it's /var, so

```
cd /var
du -h --max-depth=1 .
```

rinse and repeat until you find the files eating the disk space.
If you can't seem to find and files that fit the bill then it could be that they have been deleted but not yet released by the program writing to them to try

```
lsof +L1 /
```

which will list open files that have been deleted. You will need to determine which process has the file open and restart it to get it to release the file.

Comment: For example if see `httpd     15739  apache  txt    REG 146,70     341712     1 20484703 /usr/sbin/httpd` it means that need to `service httpd restart`?